# Adding to a numeric matrix with data from a dataframe

Tags: r, matrix

I'm wondering if I am missing a faster way of doing the following, other than doing a laborious loop.

Say I have a matrix like this:

```
m1 <- structure(c(0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("AK", "JW", "SZ"), c("AK", "JW", "SZ")))

#m1
#    AK JW SZ
# AK  0  1  1
# JW  2  0  1
# SZ  2  1  0
```

Now, I want to add values from the following dataframe. Here you can see individuals listed in 'id1' and 'id2' and a value to add in 'val'.

```
dfx <- structure(list(id1 = c("JW", "SZ", "SZ"), id2 = c("AK", "AK", 
"JW"), val = c(1.5, 2.5, 1)), .Names = c("id1", "id2", "val"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")

#dfx
#  id1 id2 val
#1  JW  AK 1.5
#2  SZ  AK 2.5
#3  SZ  JW 1.0
```

Each value should be added to the respective cell of the matrix e.g 2.5 should be added to `m1[SZ, AK]`. However, the same value should be added to the transposed cell, i.e. 2.5 should also be added to `m1[AK, SZ]`.

The resulting matrix should look like:

```
#    AK  JW  SZ
#AK 0.0 2.5 3.5
#JW 3.5 0.0 2.0
#SZ 4.5 2.0 0.0
```

This can be achieved for instance by creating a loop that essentially does this for every row of 'dfx':

```
m1[rownames(m1)=="JW",rownames(m1)=="AK"] <- m1[rownames(m1)=="JW",rownames(m1)=="AK"] + 1.5
m1[rownames(m1)=="AK",rownames(m1)=="JW"] <- m1[rownames(m1)=="AK",rownames(m1)=="JW"] + 1.5
```

Any ideas/pointers for a better way appreciated:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible `base` alternative where the data frame is reshaped to the same dimensions as the matrix. This is achieved by first converting 'id1' and 'id2' to `factor`s with `levels` picked from 'm1'. Then `xtabs` is used for reshaping. The result and its `t`ranspose are added to 'm1'.

```
dfx[ , c("id1", "id2")] <- lapply(dfx[ , c("id1", "id2")], function(x) factor(x, levels = rownames(m1)))
m2 <- xtabs(val ~ ., data = dfx)
m1 + m2 + t(m2)

#     AK  JW  SZ
# AK 0.0 2.5 3.5
# JW 3.5 0.0 2.0
# SZ 4.5 2.0 0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the cbind(x,y) as an index for assignment is a standard R strategy:

```
 m1[with(dfx, cbind(id1,id2)) ] <- m1[with(dfx, cbind(id1,id2)) ]+ # the prior values
                                   dfx$val                         # the new values
 m1
#-------------------
    AK JW SZ
AK 0.0  1  1
JW 3.5  0  1
SZ 4.5  2  0
# Step 2 for the transposed addition
m1[with(dfx, cbind(id2,id1)) ] <- m1[with(dfx, cbind(id2,id1)) ]+ 
                                    dfx$val
m1
#---------
    AK  JW  SZ
AK 0.0 2.5 3.5
JW 3.5 0.0 2.0
SZ 4.5 2.0 0.0
```

Comment: this is neat but doesn't answer the question directly.  It only adds value to half the matrix.

Comment: Didn't actually see the transpose component. Just do same procedure with indices into dfx swapped.

Comment: @BondedDust Nothing can beat this solution :-)

Comment: How a bout if one did it in one step using: `with(dfx, rbind( cbind(id2,id1), unname(cbind(id1,id2)) ))`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
library(reshape2)
Un1 <- sort(unique(unlist(dfx[,1:2])))
dfy <- expand.grid(id1=Un1, id2=Un1)
m2 <- acast(merge(dfx,dfy, all=TRUE), id1~id2, value.var='val', fill=0)
m2[upper.tri(m2)] <- m2[lower.tri(m2)]
m1+m2
#    AK  JW  SZ
#AK 0.0 2.5 3.5
#JW 3.5 0.0 2.0
#SZ 4.5 2.0 0.0
```

Or you may try `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 m2 <- acast(setkey(setDT(dfx), id1, id2)[
      CJ(id1=Un1, id2=Un1)], id1~id2, value.var='val', fill=0)
 m2+t(m2)+m1
 #    AK  JW  SZ
 #AK 0.0 2.5 3.5
 #JW 3.5 0.0 2.0
 #SZ 4.5 2.0 0.0
```